# C++ OpenGL memory leak

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

First of all, I'm a beginner in c++.
I'm writing my own game engine.
Code is below.

**Sprite.cpp**

```
#include "Sprite.h"


Sprite::Sprite(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath)
{
    init(x, y, width, height, shader, texturePath, STBI_rgb_alpha);
}

Sprite::Sprite(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath, int reg_comp)
{
    init(x, y, width, height, shader, texturePath, reg_comp);
}
void Sprite::init(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath, int reg_comp)
{
    this->shader = &shader;
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        width/2+x,  height/2+y, 0.0f,  /* Top Right */                  1.0f, 1.0f,
        width/2 + x, -height / 2 + y, 0.0f,  /* Bottom Right*/          1.0f, 0.0f,
        -width/2 + x, -height / 2 + y, 0.0f,  /* Bottom Left*/          0.0f, 0.0f,
        -width / 2 + x,  height / 2 + y, 0.0f,   /* Top Left */         0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,  // 1
        1, 2, 3   // 2
    };
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Position
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // TexCoord
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    texture = new Texture(texturePath, reg_comp);
    transformShaderLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader.program, "transform");
    glProgramUniform4fv(shader.program, transformShaderLocation, 1, transform);

}


Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    delete texture;
}


void Sprite::Draw() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->texture); //?
    //glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->program, "ourTexture"), 0); //?
    shader->Use();
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


void Sprite::Transform(int x, int y) {
    glProgramUniform4fv(shader->program, transformShaderLocation, 1, transform);
}

void Sprite::setTexture(Texture *texture) {
    delete this->texture;
    this->texture = texture;
}
```

**Sprite.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "Shader.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "Texture.h"
#include <stb_image.h>



class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath);
    Sprite(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath, int reg_comp);

    ~Sprite();
    void Draw();
    void Transform(int x, int y);
    void setTexture(Texture *texture);

private:
    void init(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat width, GLfloat height, Shader& shader, char *texturePath, int reg_comp);
    GLuint VBO = 0, VAO = 0, EBO = 0;
    GLint transformShaderLocation;
    Shader* shader;
    GLfloat transform[4] = {
        1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f
    };
    Texture *texture;

};
```

**Texture.cpp**

```
#include "Texture.h"


Texture::Texture(char *texturePath, int reg_comp)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);

    int _width, _height, _ImageComponents;

    unsigned char *image = stbi_load(texturePath, &_width, &_height, &_ImageComponents, reg_comp);
    if (image == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "error loading image" << std::endl;
    }


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


    // Set our texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _width, _height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    if (_ImageComponents == 3)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, _width, _height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    else if (_ImageComponents == 4)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _width, _height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image); //RGBA8?


    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(image);
}


Texture::~Texture()
{
}
```

**Texture.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stb_image.h>


class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(char *texturePath, int reg_comp);
    ~Texture();
    GLuint texture = 0;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Main main;
    return main.init();
}
int Main::init() {

    display = new Display( 800, 600, "OpenGL" );
    shader = new Shader("Shaders/default.vert", "Shaders/default.frag");

    sprite = new Sprite(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, *shader, "Textures/texture1.png");
    sprite2 = new Sprite(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, *shader, "Textures/texture2.png", STBI_rgb);



    while (!display->isClosed()) {
        update();
    }
    delete display;
    delete shader;
    delete sprite;
    delete sprite2;
    return 0;
}

void Main::update() {

    draw();
    display->Update();

    if (debug == 0) {
        texture->setTexture(new Texture("Textures/texture1.png", STBI_rgb_alpha));
        debug = 1;
    }
    else if (debug == 1) {
        texture->setTexture(new Texture("Textures/texture2.png", STBI_rgb));
        debug = 0;
    }

}

void Main::draw() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);;
    sprite->Draw();
    sprite->Draw();
}
```

**main.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Display.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "Sprite.h"



class Main {
public:
    int init();

private:
    void draw();
    void update();
    Display *display;
    Shader *shader;
    Triangle *triangle, *triangle2;
    Sprite *sprite, *sprite2;
    int debug = 0;
};
```

You see, everytime a new texture is created, the last texture is deleted.
However, if I open the task manager the memory usage goes up and up.
Why is that so?
(If I remove setTexture(new...) everything is fine, so this is the problem.

Comment: use valgrind to check where you have leak

Comment: Where you set the texture pointer to NULL with a question comment about necessary, it's not, you immediately write a new pointer there. There is no need to NULL a deleted pointer.

Comment: The leak is probably in the Sprite class. Could you show it to us?
My guess is that the Sprite object does not free the Texture object by itself.

Comment: Allocating a texture every frame is a waste of electrons. You should strive to minimise pointers and new and delete in your code.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I just wanted to test if changing textures works. I will reuse the textures of course. But what's so bad about pointers? I mean if I delete them correctly there won't be any problems, am I correct?

Comment: Pointers are error prone and break all kinds of nice assumptions (and "if" in your comment is a big if, like ihis: **IF**). Use std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr if you must use pointers.

Comment: How pointers are error prone? One simple rule to follow when using them: "call delete if and only if you called new", apart from that pointers are just numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are your `glDelete…` calls? (`glDeleteTextures`, `glDeleteBuffers`). Deallocating your class instances with the `delete` operator will not magically do the proper deletion steps with OpenGL unless you do it explicitly in the destructor.

Comment: Thank you, deleting the textures in the destructor fixes it. The tutorial I was following didn't mention that :/

Answer (score 1):

When I am programming OpenGL stuff, i now use wrapper around all handles. If you use GLuint it is very likely to forget some setup or deletion code. Depending on your coding skills, these wrappers can be very generic or you can use the shared pointer for this purpose.